# Isolate k8s pods network between namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I need to isolate k8s pods network between namespaces.

A `pod-1` running in namespace `ns-1` cannot access the network from a `pod-2` in namespace `ns-2`.

The purpose of it, is creating a sandbox between namespaces and prevent network communications between specific pods based on it labels.

I was trying the [NetworkPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) to do this, but my knowledge about k8s is a little "crude".

Is this possible? Can someone provide an example?

---

I'm trying to block all intranet comunication and allow internet using this:

```yaml
spec:
  egress:
  - ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
    to:
    - ipBlock:
    cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
        - 10.0.0.0/8
        - 192.168.0.0/16
        - 172.16.0.0/12
        - 172.40.0.0/16
    - namespaceSelector: {}
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: kube-dns
  podSelector:
    matchExpressions:
    - key: camel.apache.org/integration
      operator: Exists
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

But when I access something like google.com, it resolves the DNS correctly but not connects resulting in timeout.

The policy intention is to:

- block all private network access
- allow only the kube-dns nameserver resolver on port 53
- but allow all access to internet

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster (your config file)? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm using an minikube for testing local and the prod env is a AWS EKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings of [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) are very flexible, and you can configure it in different way. If we look to your case, then you have to create 2 policies for your cluster. First it is namespace network policy for your production and second one is for your sandbox. Of course, before to start to modify your network be sure that you choose, install, and configure network [provider.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#how-to-implement-the-kubernetes-networking-model)
It is example of NetworkPolicy .yaml file for isolate your name NameSpace:

```
# You can create a "default" policy for a namespace which prevents all ingress
# AND egress traffic by creating the following NetworkPolicy in that namespace.
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all
  namespace: YourSandbox
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

And after that you can create your pod in this NameSpace and it will be isolated. Just add to your config file string with NameSpace name:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-c
  namespace: YourSandbox
```

And in this example, we add access to connect outside and inside to specific NameSpace and service:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: access-service-c
  namespace: YourSandbox
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: YourSandboxService
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          env: YourProdactionNameSpase
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: NameOfYourService
   egress:
   - to:
     - namespaceSelector:
         matchLabels:
           name: YourProdactionNameSpase
     - podSelector:
         matchLabels:
           app: NameOfYourService
```

Use this  network policy ip Block to configure the egress blocking the default local private network IPs and allow the rest of the internet access open.

```
egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except: 192.168.40.0/24 #Your pul of local private network IPs
```

If you use the length of the subnet prefix /32, that indicates that you are limiting the scope of the rule to this one IP address only.

Comment: can you provide an example how to use the `ipBlock` to configure the `egress` blocking the default local private network IPs and allow the rest of the internet access open?

Comment: Could you answer me, did my decision help you? If yes, you could follow [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) recommendations for evaluating responses.

Comment: Sorry about the delay... I'm trying to isolate my pods in my intranet, and free the internet using this https://pastebin.com/TU8GTC40 but it isn't working. Can you help?